# Оператор выбора Switch-Case

Tags: java

Локатор ориентирован на одну из сторон света («С» — север, «З» — запад, «Ю» — юг, «В» — восток) и может принимать три цифровые ко- манды поворота: 1 — поворот налево, –1 — поворот направо, 2 — поворот на 180°. Дан символ C — исходная ориентация локатора и целые числа N1 и N2 — две посланные команды. Вывести ориентацию локатора после выполнения этих команд.
Надо написать код на Java

Answer (score 1):

Оператор выбора упрощает цепочку логических условий.

В общем случае можно записать условие через `if`

```
if(myvar==0){
  // действие
} else if(myvar==1){
  // действие
} else {
  throw new IllegalStateException("Команда отсутствует");
}
```

Но это не так удобно как с помощью `switch`

```
switch(myvar) { 
  case 0:
   // действие
   break; 
  case 1:
   // действие
   break; 
  default:
   throw new IllegalStateException("Команда отсутствует");
}
```

Данной информации вам должно хватить. Вперёд к решению!

Comment: Можете объяснить про throw new IllegalStateException?

Comment: @NemoKhan Мы просто прерываем исполнение функции, так как такой команды нет, можете заменить на System.out.println("Команда отсутствует");